# Checking for 2 exact string in a text file using grep

Tags: shell-script, grep

I'm totally new to shell scripting and I have been reading up on tutorials on how to use different `grep` function. Unfortunately, most of the tutorial usually talk about grepping a certain pattern of the string from the text file.

However, I'm trying to search for two exact strings in the text file.

For example, here is the content of my `BookDB.txt`:

```
Three Little Pigs : Mary Jane
Cinderella : Paul Johnson
```

I tried to get the user input by using the `read` function

```
echo Title :
read Title 

echo Author : 
read Author
```

Next, I used the `grep` command which I gotten help from this [link](//unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206903/match-exact-string-using-grep) to get the string and check if it exist in the `BookDB.txt` file and assign the `echo $?` command output into a variable to display out  some message.

```
grep -w "$Title" BookDB.txt
check1=`echo $?`    

grep -w "$Author" BookDB.txt    
check2=`echo $?`

if [ "$check1" -eq 0 ] && [ "$check2" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo Found
else
    echo Not Found
fi
```

Even though, the user typed `Three` as the `Title` and `Mary` as the `Author`, `echo$?` command still returns 0. Whenever, it returns 0, it displays out the information from the text file which is not required.

Comment: `grep`'s exit status is non-zero when there's no match - why would you expect it to display anything in that case?

Comment: How are the strings separated? Always through `:`? Then `-w` is not for you, if you know Regex, `-w str` is basically the same as `\bstr\b`, meaning that a word is separated using white spaces or start/end of line/document.

Comment: @phk yes they are.

Comment: @steeldriver I'm just trying to store the output variable from the grep command via the `echo $?` command.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you would want to do. Do you, for example, want to get the name of the author out when querying with a title?

Comment: Ditto. Your question is unclear. Please try to explain more clearly what you want to do; what output you want to get from what inputs. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: I tried editing to make the question more clearer. Hope you all get a better picture now.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan There was a mistake I fixed, your forgot the `$` when referring the variables. BTW, if you are using `bash` you can (and IMHO should) use `[[`/`]]` instead of `[`/`]`. Also, please make every question only about a single problem and not a live programming session. Also, what about my answer?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Why remove the `bash` tag? Just because OP's code snippets were not bash-specific?

Comment: Correct, @phk -- it'd apply to any shell

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
check=`echo $?`
```

You are making the shell expand `$?` to compose the command `echo $?` and then assigning its output to the variable. If you want to save the return status of a command, cut the middle man and just do this:

```
check=$?
```

However, in your case you don't need to save the return status. The `if` statement is capable of the `&&` test by itself.

So if you want to find a text file that contains two strings, do as follows:

```
if grep -qwF "$Author" "BookDB.txt" && grep -qwF "$Title" "BookDB.txt"; then
    echo Yes
fi
```

The option `-q` is to supress `grep`'s output, and `-F` is to not parse the pattern as a regular expression.

However, what you most likely is looking for is a line that contains the title followed by the author name, given your example. So you could try this:

```
if grep -q "^\\s*$Title\\s*:\\s*$Author\\s*\$" "BookDB.txt"; then
    echo yes
fi
```

This will require the user to type the full title and full author name, as well as getting the case right. So maybe you'd like something a bit more permissive:

```
if grep -qi "$Title.*:.*$Author" "BookDB.txt"; then
    echo yes
fi
```

Now you don't care about case and you don't require full names (`John` and `john` both match `JOHN CAVENDISH`). Same aplies to title.

---

The following MCVE

```
echo Title:
read Title
echo Author:
read Author
if grep -qi "$Title.*:.*$Author" "BookDB.txt"; then
    echo Found
fi
```

works for the following "BookDB.txt" file:

> Book Title:AuthorName
>   Book Title : authorname
>   Book title: Authorname
>   book : authorName

with the test case `book` and `author`.

Comment: you're right that i'm trying to look for the title followed by the author name. However, i tried your 3rd example but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you get an error message? Try manually assigning `Title=pigs` and `Author=mary` just before the `if`.

Comment: it still doesn't work. I tried using this code of yours `if grep -q "^\\s*$Title\\s*:\\s*$Author\\s*\$" "BookDB.txt"` and added an else condition behind, but it is displaying the else condition when i typed the correct information from the `BookDB.txt`

Comment: Check if `echo "no work" | grep "no\\swork"; echo $?` prints 0.

Comment: Could you post an MCVE of your script and a small BookDB.txt that fails? It doesn't make sense to me that this isn't woking. Also, have you tried my last example? It's probably the best (of my suggestions) for what you want to do anyway.

Comment: @giusti It does not work in ancient `grep` versions as can be probably in OS X. In FreeBSD it prints 1.

Comment: Ah! That's good to know. And if that's really the case, then OP should just use `[[:blank:]]` instead of `\\s`. The character classes `[[::]]` are more GNUish anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Well, you *still* haven’t said what output you want from what input,
so I’m going to have to guess. 
I guess you want to do one thing (e.g., output “Found”)
if the user enters `Title="Three Little Pigs"` and `Author="Mary Jane"`,
 or if the user enters `Title="Cinderella"` and `Author="Paul Johnson"`
(or any other line in the file), and something else
(e.g., output “Not Found”) if the user enters *anything else*
(e.g., `Title="Three` and `Author="Mary"`,
or `Title="Three Little Pigs"` and `Author="Paul Johnson"`). 
I suggest that you build on [phk’s answer](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/337596/80216#337598) and do

```
if grep "^\s*$Title\s*:\s*$Author\s*$" BookDB.txt > /dev/null
then
    echo "Found"
else
    echo "Not Found"
fi
```

or you could change the first line to

```
if grep -x "\s*$Title\s*:\s*$Author\s*" BookDB.txt > /dev/null
```

Notes:

- `^` represents the beginning of the line.
- `$` represents the end of the line.
- Therefore, `^pattern$` represents the *`pattern`*
  taking up the entire line.
- `grep -x "pattern"` also represents the *`pattern`*
  taking up the entire line. 
  If you read [Match exact string using grep](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/206903/80216) more carefully,
  you’ll see that you have confused `-w` and `-x`.
- `\s` means a space character. 
  `\s*` means zero or more space character(s).
- Putting it all together: the pattern means
  zero or more space character(s) at the beginning of the line,
  followed by the title, followed by zero or more space(s), a colon,
  zero or more space(s), the author, and zero or more space(s)
  (and nothing else on the line).
- Use `> /dev/null`
  to prevent the matching line(s) from appearing on the output
  (i.e., the screen). 
  As [giusti](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/337596/80216#337604) points out,
  you could also use the `-q` (or `--quiet` or `--silent`) option to do that.

As pointed out by [phk](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/337596/80216#337598), you may get unexpected/undesired results
if the title or the author’s name includes a colon,
or if the user enters any character(s)
that are special in regular expressions
(e.g., `^`, `$`, `\`, `*`, `[`, `]`, **`.`**,
or sometimes `(`, `)`, `{`, `}`, `?` and `+`).